# How can assign String values to Matrix in java?

Tags: java, android, string, google-maps, matrix

Hi guys I'm new on java programming. I have my android app and I'm trying to build a matrix with values comes from the markers on a googlemap map. All is going well but when I try to assign to a matrix some values it goes in exception (NullPointerException). The markers datas I read from an xml file on the sd card and the xml parser works well. This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < markers.getLength(); i++) {
    Element item = (Element) markers.item(i);
    Data[i][0] = item.getAttribute("name");
    Data[i][1] = item.getAttribute("address");
    Data[i][2] = item.getAttribute("lat");
}
```

This is the statement of the matrix (some rows above):

```
String [][]Data;
```

Comment: `Data` is a reference type, it's default value is `null`, it's uninitialized. Read about `new`.

Comment: Ah ok so in Java I have to init matrix. Thank you. @MarounMaroun

Comment: @MarounMaroun I can't know how large will be the matrix so It's correct if I do: String [][]Data = new String [][]; ?

Comment: yes @PierpaoloErcoli the thing Maroun said is absolutely agreable

Comment: Very well, I solved thank you all :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the first dimension atleast. The second can be decided dynamically.

```
String[][] Data = new String [3][]; 
Data[0] = new String[5];  // 5 cols
Data[1] = new String[2];  // 2 cols
```

If you want both dynamic, consider using `List<List<String>>`